# Python - Pagination loop

Tags: python, loops, pagination

I have one question.
In my code i have:

```
r = session.get("https://xxxxxxx.com/online/GIRL")
print (r.status_code)
print (r.cookies)
soups = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')


def getPeopleLinks(page):
    links = []
    for link in soups.find_all('a'):
        url = link.get('href')
        if url:
            if 'profile/' in url:
                links.append(url)
    return links
```

How i can get list of all profiles on the all available pages? (ex. 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc)?
and put it to Links[]

The webcode is:

```
<div class="pages"><span>1</span>
<a href="online/GIRL/2">2</a>
<a href="online/GIRL/3">3</a>
<a href="online/GIRL/4">4</a>
<a accesskey="x" href="online/GIRL/2">Next</a></div>
```

Thanks!

ADDED:
Thanks for answer. Others pagination site have the same html as main site, so i need only read all users from all pagination (2,3,4,5 etc)
For my main site all working fine, i only need to add all users from all pagination sites to LINKS[]

```
login_data = {
    'login': 'xxxxx',
    'pass': 'xxxx',
    'back_url': '' 
    }

def getPeopleLinks(page):
    links = []
    for link in soups.find_all('a'):
        url = link.get('href')
        if url:
            if 'profil/' in url:
                links.append(url)
    return links

with requests.Session() as session:
        url = "https://xxxxx.com/login/?form_login=1"

        post = session.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
print (post.status_code)
print (post.cookies)
r = session.get("https://xxxx.com/online/Girls")
print (r.status_code)
print (r.cookies)
soups = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
x = getPeopleLinks(soups)
print(x)
for path in x:
    sleep(3)
    url = 'http://www.xxxx.com' + path
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print(url)
```

The output is:
http://www.xxxx.com/profile/nickname

That its all working fine, but only for:

```
https://xxxx.com/online/Girls
```

I need to read all users from all pagination sites

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the HTML script that is associated with the page? We do not know which tag elements/ids are needed to grab that specific data

Comment: Thanks for answer. I added code to my post! :)